# Received symbol lookup error after running apt-get

Tags: apt, 20.04

After running :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now I am trying to install any package using apt-get I received this error:

```
apt-get: symbol lookup error: 
apt-get: undefined symbol:
 _Z15InstallPackagesR9CacheFilebbb, version APTPRIVATE_0.0
```

I am using ubuntu 20.04.

---

```
$ which apt-get
/usr/local/bin/apt-get

$file $(which apt-get)

/usr/local/bin/apt-get: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=dd9a6ba81bc20f363c3246a66e6197ff273b3720, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped 

$ dd $(which apt-get):

dd: unrecognized operand ‘/usr/local/bin/apt-get’ Try 'dd --help' for more information.

$ apt-cache policy apt
apt-cache: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.4.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Edit:**

I was able to solve it by installing the packages from : http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/

```
> sudo dpkg --force-all -i <.deb filename>

> sudo apt install -f

> sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

Thank you all.

Comment: **which apt-get:** `/usr/local/bin/apt-get`

**file $(which apt-get):**

`/usr/local/bin/apt-get: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=dd9a6ba81bc20f363c3246a66e6197ff273b3720, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped`


**dd $(which apt-get):**

`dd: unrecognized operand ‘/usr/local/bin/apt-get’
Try 'dd --help' for more information.`

**apt-cache policy apt:**

`apt-cache: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.4.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Somehow you have a modified apt-get which is NOT system installed, that's why you're getting symbol failures, you don't have the dependent libraries for that `apt-get` on your system.  Did yuo make any revisions on your system such as update or manually install newer package versions, or perhaps have a failed upgrade happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by installing the packages from http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i <.deb filename>
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

Comment: I am getting the same problem here. Could you tell me exactly what packages did you installe? All of them? Could you help me with more detailed information? I just did the normal `apt-get upgrade`

Comment: No, not all of them try to install libstdc or libapt-pkg

and then:
 sudo dpkg --force-all -i <.deb filename>