# apt-get lookup error

Tags: 20.04

ubuntu 20.04.2  LTS run apt-get command, then get:

```
apt-get: symbol lookup error: apt-get: undefined symbol: _Z16InstallPackagesR9CacheFilebbbRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK11CommandLine, version APTPRIVATE_0.0
```

How to solve this, thanks in advance, guys~~~

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Received symbol lookup error after running apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350955/received-symbol-lookup-error-after-running-apt-get)

Comment: hi zwets, no, it does not help me..... I tried all libapt versions and re-installed libstdc.... upgrade my libapt will cause preference file lost.......